# Windows: Have a dedicated MS Visual C/C++ toolchain

Tags: compiler, windows

For a CI system and the developers in our team, I'd like to be able to use a specific version of a MSVC toolchain for native Windows builds.

The goal is to have a well-defined consistent build-environment for all developers and for the the CI system, so that we know what toolchain was used to build a SW.

Afaik, the MSVC compilers on Windows are installed with MS Visual Studio, and which version one uses probably depends on the version of Visual Studio and maybe the Windows version (7/8/10...).

On a Linux system, such a dedicated toolchain is typically provided as an archive and put under `/opt`, so it does not get affected due to system upgrades or the general Linux version/distribution (as opposed to `/usr/bin/g++` et. al.)

- **How can I achieve this on Windows systems?**
- *And is a Windows-docker-container an option or maybe the only option?*

Comment: Windows docker container is only an option for the most recent Windows Server editions.  Unfortunately, I'm a long ways removed from C/C++ toolchains to speak towards how to set that up.  You may find that you need to set up a straight VM for C/C++ builds.

Comment: It's been a long time since I had to work with MSVC++, but as far as I remember, all projects are usually set to a specific [toolset/toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517662/what-is-platform-toolset-setting-in-visual-studio-project) and those toolchains can be installed as [standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504552/how-to-install-visual-c-build-tools) (no VS) packages. So with few initial preparatory/install/build scripts, there should be no issues with having a (in no way ideal) but basically the same consistent environment on dev/build machines. But obviously...

Comment: for really reliable reproducible environments you will probably have to go fully [containerized](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-msvc-in-a-docker-container-for-your-c-projects/)/VM. Hadn't tried that, so can't really give any practical advice.

Comment: I have a related question for Linux. Does anybody have any answer to provide? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/what-is-an-example-of-a-modern-build-and-cd-pipeline-for-c